# How to link to new pages in Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

This may be a very stupid question. I made a new page in Magento and I want to make a link to the page on my Magento homepage, but I dont know what the link url to use for that page. The url key for my page is `over-ons` My base url is: `127.0.0.1/html/magento/magento` I cant seem to find out how to get to my new page. How do I link this to the home page? I've seen a tutorial on the official magento website itself and it said you have to make a new category but that doesn't seem right for such a small thing. How do I get to my new page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your page ( CMS > Pages )
and use this code

```
{{store url='over-ons'}}
```

Check this link for other shortcodes available for static blocks and pages - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mr. Sergey Korzhov.

There is another option to **Insert Variable** in cms >> pages.

When you click on that button, it will show a list of available Magento variables.

By clicking on **Base Unsecure Url** or **Base Secure Url** links you can insert dynamic website url.

After that paste url key. It will make the url you desired.